# Android App Links on Android 12 - `legacy_failure`

Tags: android, react-native, android-app-links

I'm working on a React Native app that is supposed to open when you click on a link that leads to the website. The iOS and Android 10 versions work just fine.

However, on Android 12 instead of opening the app the link opens in the browser. I have `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file in place that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.example",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF...", // staging key fingerprint
        "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF..."  // prod key fingerprint
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I read [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) through and through trying to find a solution to this.
I tried running `adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify com.example` and executing `adb shell pm get-app-links com.example`, but I keep getting the result:

```
Domain verification state:
      example.com: legacy_failure
```

I also tried the [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) tool by Google. It says that there's no app deep linking permission on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but after a few more tries it shows success.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example">
  <application ...>
    <.../>
    <activity ...>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="example.com" />
      </intent-filter>
      <.../>
    </activity>
    <.../>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried changing `android:host` to `www.example.com` or `*.example.com` but that didn't seem to work either.